# modify Peterson’s 2-process algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Is it possible to change Peterson’s 2-process algorithm so that its contention-free complexity ( its complexity when a process runs solo) will have only three accesses?
in the original version, it has 4 accesses.

peterson's algorithem:

```
initialization:
bool flag[0] = {false};
bool flag[1] = {false};
int turn;

P0: 
flag[0] = true;
P0_gate: turn = 1;
         while (flag[1] == true && turn == 1)
         {
             // busy wait
         }
         // critical section
         ...
         // end of critical section
         flag[0] = false;

P1:    
flag[1] = true;
P1_gate: turn = 0;
         while (flag[0] == true && turn == 0)
         {
             // busy wait
         }
         // critical section
         ...
         // end of critical section
         flag[1] = false;
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you added a link to the algorithm..

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can do that - you cannot eliminate the raising and lowering of `flag[i]` as that is your "I'm interested in the critical section" which is critical for Peterson's, so you can only play with the test.

If you eliminate the `flag[j]` test you will deadlock yourself in a contention-free case, and if you eliminate the `turn` test (and the `turn` register as it is now useless) you will deadlock under contention.

If you reorder the `flag[j]` read and the `turn` write, you might get away with three accesses in the contention-free case, but under contention you can still dead-lock if `j` exits their critical section after you test their flag, or at least block until `j` comes back to claim the critical section - which will get you a fully serialized processing: both locked and unlocked code is serialized.

QED

(sorry, but this really sounds like a CS course question).

BTW: the original algorithm assumes you can read `flag[j]` and `turn` in parallel for performance (assuming that atomic access is slow but can be parallelized across registers), but then you can't take advantage of short-circuit boolean evaluation so you actually have 5 accesses in both scenarios.